# Why doesn't my toggle button open my responsive menu with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I want the `nav` menu to open when the hamburger menu in the first `ul` is clicked.  I used JavaScript to target the `nav-list` class in the 2nd `ul` but when I click, nothing happens.

I initially had the hamburger icon and links in one list and tried using `display: none` for everything except the first li item but realized I couldn't get the `getElementsByClassName` to show the rest of the li items on click.

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navList = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-list')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navList.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
/* Nav Styling */

.navbar-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.nav-icon li {
  display: none;
}


/* When menu icon clicked, javascript shows nav items */

@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  /* Responsive Navbar */
  .nav-icon li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-list ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-list li a {
    padding: .5 rem 1 rem;
  }
  /* For Javascript */
  .nav-list.active {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul class="nav-icon" id="nav-icon">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="activities.html">SELF-HELP TOOLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="conditions.html">CONDITIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="contacts.html">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your `nav-list li` is `display: none` not `nav-list` this is the reason it is not displaying . Change that `display: none` property to `nav-list`

Comment: I want the icon from nav-icon to act as a button display the list items from nav-list when the screen is 740px or less.  Removing li from nav-list displays the list and the icon simultaneously and when I click the icon, it changes from a row to a column instead of only displaying a column when clicked at the smaller screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this is what you want : When you click on menu icon(here have given as `A`) list configuration changes from row to column on subsequent clicks .

Then you should (not only because of above said) but `display: none` on `nav-list` not on `nav-list li` as in your JavaScript `function` you are `toggling` `active` on  `nav-list` not on `nav-list li` .

> It is your call either change CSS or change JavaScript function

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navList = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-list')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navList.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
/* Nav Styling */

.navbar-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.nav-icon li {
  display: none;
}


/* When menu icon clicked, javascript shows nav items */

@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  /* Responsive Navbar */
  .nav-icon li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-list {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-list ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-list li a {
    padding: .5 rem 1 rem;
  }
  /* For Javascript */
  .nav-list.active {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul class="nav-icon" id="nav-icon">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <i class="fa fa-bars">A</i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="activities.html">SELF-HELP TOOLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="conditions.html">CONDITIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="contacts.html">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Correct I want to use Javascript to display the nav-list items and css to change the list items to column on the smaller screen.  I'm still new at this so sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: Is this is what you wanted to achieve as I pasted the code or something else

Comment: Not quite.  I figured it out.  I had to change my javascript function and use a queryselector to target the navlist in order to change the links from row to column.  Thanks for your help.